# How to solve SSAS OLAP error in deploying the cube

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssas

So I have tried to deploy the Worldwide Importers cube to the SSAS, but with no luck.
I have pretty much used all the other methods, from creating a local Microsoft account to a virtual machine to reinstalling everything, and so on.

The problem is that my group mate and I have exactly the same setup ( excluding the data source and all of those that are personal) and for him works and for me doesn't...

Also to top it off, I have tried to deploy the AdventureWorks and for it, no errors were found, while for WWI no solutions worked.

Can you please guide me , as i have no clue how to solve it and its necessary for my project.

[Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9OhB.png)

Comment: Can you screenshot the 12 warnings? Crazy as it should’ve those usually contain the root problem.

Comment: @GregGalloway the errors are added in Figure 1 link. They are all related to OLAP and some attributes that do not match for some reason. But on my college's project(which is the same) works without any issue

Comment: can you screenshot the warnings and the other errors?

Comment: @GregGalloway https://imgur.com/KX2BMm9  ; is there any way we can have a chat on discord ? maybe it is much faster in solving the problem....

Comment: well it wasn’t the warnings. I suspect one of the truncated error messages is the culprit. Can you copy the full error messages into the body of your question?

Comment: @GregGalloway the errors are all the same in both picture, the errors are the same even after i tried to make another user, change the server and many more, i sent my solution to my teacher and for her it worked and gave me some info, i tried that as well and again the same errors. Im just a about to give up as there is no way for me to do the project ...